# Creating A Currency Per Hour Field

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to produce a field in a MS Access file that calculates one type of variable against another.

The variables are currency per time.

How would "£/hr" or salary per hour be written in Microsoft Access
Is it possible?

Comment: One possibility would be a [calculated field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-combine-fields-using-the-calculated-data-type-2a290bbc-46f6-42ae-8590-6fbc497d1de9).

Comment: I'm assuming from your question that you are working with multiple currencies, is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I hope your not retired.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I hope your not retired. No difference in currency. It to calculate wage I would pay out for each hour, that the issue is formulating my field so that currency and time occupy the same column, if this is possible to create hrs/currency!

Comment: _currency and time occupy the same column_. Not possible, other than creating it as _text_ which you would never do.

Answer (score 0):

Use data type *Currency*. A value could be £50.

Then, If `[HoursWorked]` is another field of data type *Currency* and having the hours worked, use a query to calculate the salary:

```
Salary: [SaleryPerHour] * [HoursWorked]
```

If `[HoursWorked]` holds 4.5, `Salary` will be £225.00

Comment: Thank you, but would I still have to add yet another field for 'total'?

Comment: Not sure what _total_ means here. After calculating the _Salary_ for each employee, you can use that query as source for yet a query or a report where you sum the salaries to a total.